# Cannot get this simple sed command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

This `sed` command is described as follows

> Delete the cars that are $10,000 or more. Pipe the output of the `sort` into a `sed` to do this, by quitting as soon as we match a regular expression representing 5 (or more) digits at the end of a record (DO NOT use repetition for this):

So far the command is:

```
$ grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5
```

I have to add another pipe at the end of that command I think which "quits as soon as we match a regular expression representing 5 or more digits at the end of a record"

I tried things like

```
$ grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5 | sed "/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ q"
```

and other variations within the `//` but nothing works! What is the command which matches a regular expression representing 5 or more digits and quits according to this question?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output of `grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5`?

Comment: Nominally, you should add a `$` before the second `/` to match the 5 digits at the end of the record.

Comment: Is there a comma in the output?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that was it, all i did was add "$" before the second / and it worked thanks!

Comment: For future reference, a $ at the end of a regex will only match if the match occurs at the end of the string, likewise ^ anchors to the begining of the string. `/^only match this string exactly$/` would only match if the literal string "only match this string exactly" was the exact line inspected with the regular expression

Comment: Incidentally, when you said "but nothing works", it would have been helpful to show what output, if any, you got from your sample command.  And the question/comment by @renab is right on the mark; it helps everyone if you show what you are getting as output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nominally, you should add a `$` before the second `/` to match 5 digits at the end of the record.  If you omit the `$`, then any sequence of 5 digits will cause `sed` to quit, so if there is another number (a VIN, perhaps) before the price, it might match when you didn't intend it to.

```
grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5 | sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/q'
```

On the whole, it's safer to use single quotes around the regex, unless you need to substitute a shell variable into it (or unless the regex contains single quotes itself).  You can also specify the repetition:

```
grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5 | sed '/[0-9]\{5,\}$/q'
```

The `\{5,\}` part matches 5 or more digits.  If for any reason that doesn't work, you might find you're using GNU `sed` and you need to do something like `sed --posix` to get it working in the normal mode.  Or you might be able to just remove the backslashes.  There certainly are options to GNU `sed` to change the regex mechanism it uses (as there are with GNU `grep` too).

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

As you don't post a file sample, a did it as a guess.
Here I'm looking for lines with the word "chevy" where the field 5 is less than 10000.

awk '/chevy/ {if ( $5 < 10000 )  print $0} ' cars

I forgot the flag -i from grep ... so the correct is:

awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /chevy/ {if ( $5 < 10000 ) print $0} ' cars

$ cat > cars

Chevy 2 3 4 10000

Chevy 2 3 4 5000

chEvy 2 3 4 1000

CHEVY 2 3 4 10000

CHEVY 2 3 4 2000

Prevy 2 3 4 1000

Prevy 2 3 4 10000

$ awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /chevy/ {if ( $5 < 10000 ) print $0} ' cars

Chevy 2 3 4 5000

chEvy 2 3 4 1000

CHEVY 2 3 4 2000

Comment: awk is the answer, but it looks like "grep -iv chevy" say NOT chevy or Chevy, or CHevy, ... so  instead "grep -iv chevy cars | awk '$5 < 10000'   and no need to "print $0" since that's the default action.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that ... to do that use BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5 | sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/d'
```

Comment: Please explain your answer