# Pipe sort into sed, match 5 or more digits at the end of a record?

Tags: shell, unix

File

```
plym    fury    77      73      2500
chevy   nova    79      60      3000
ford    mustang 65      45      17000
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
ford    ltd     83      15      10500
Chevy   nova    80      50      3500
fiat    600     65      115     450
honda   accord  81      30      6000
ford    thundbd 84      10      17000
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
chevy   impala  65      85      1550
ford    bronco  83      25      9525
```

I have to delete all cars that are $10,000 or more (last column in file). I have to pipe the output of the sort into a sed to do this, by quitting when a regular expression representing 5 or more digits is match at the end of a record.

This is the command I have to pipe: `grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5`

I tried so far:

`grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5 | sed -n '/[0-9]{5}*/'`

but to no avail.

---

```
So far we have:

grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5

Now let's delete the cars that are $10,000 or more.  Pipe the output of the sort into
a sed to do this, by quitting as soon as we match a regular expression representing 5
(or more) digits at the end of a record (DO NOT use repetition for this):

You entered: grep -iv chevy cars | sort -nk 5 | sed -n '/[0-9]{5}$/'
Please try again.
```

Comment: Maybe you need to have a chat with [Albert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1854644/albert).  His question [Cannot get this simple `sed` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573092/cannot-get-this-simple-sed-command) looks almost identical to yours (he needed to delete the $10k Chevy vehicles too) so you're probably doing the same class.

Answer (score 6):

With the `-n` switch you have to explicitly `p`rint matching lines, and `!p` prints non-maching lines, i.e. cars not costing a 5-digit value. Also add `$` to the pattern to match only at the end, and escape `\{` and `\}` for the repeating group, otherwise it will match the literal string `{5}` after a digit.

So try this: `sed -n '/[0-9]\{5\}$/!p'`

If you want to quit at the first match instead of printing only relevant matches, try the `q` command instead of `!p`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ d'
```

Looks tedious, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -iv chevy cars | sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/ d'
```